# Why won't this Bootstrap Carousel swipe function work for me?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codepen

I found this codepen: https://codepen.io/andrearufo/pen/rVWpyE

and I'd love to use it, but for some reason it won't work for me, even if I copy it without changing a single thing. Why is this?

I haven't forgotten to embed bootstrap nor jquery.

I've also tried other solutions for a swipe function, but for some reason none of them worked. The only carousel where the swipe worked (I've tried in Google Chrome developer tools) was on this codepen.

```js
$(".carousel").swipe({

  swipe: function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount, fingerData) {

    if (direction == 'left') $(this).carousel('next');
    if (direction == 'right') $(this).carousel('prev');

  },
  allowPageScroll:"vertical"

});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Bootstrap default carousel with swipe and touch gestures</h1>
    <p class="lead">How to add the swipes gesture to comand the Bootstrap carousel on mobile devices.</p>
    <p>Made by <strong>Andrea Rufo</strong>, more info and tutorial on <a href="http://www.orangedropdesign.com/"> OrangeDropDesign.com</a></p>
  </div>
       

  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="4"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/1400/600?image=114">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/1400/600?image=745">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/1400/600?image=315">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/1400/600?image=622">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/1400/600?image=401">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the example you might miss `JQuery` or `Swipe` LIB.

```js
$(".carousel").swipe({

  swipe: function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount, fingerData) {

    if (direction == 'left') $(this).carousel('next');
    if (direction == 'right') $(this).carousel('prev');

  },
  allowPageScroll:"vertical"

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.touchswipe/1.6.4/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="4"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/1400/600?image=114">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/1400/600?image=315">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/1400/600?image=622">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/1400/600?image=401">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope you will got help with this

```
(function ($) {
    var touchStartX = null;

    $('.carousel').each(function () {
        var $carousel = $(this);
        $(this).on('touchstart', function (event) {
            var e = event.originalEvent;
            if (e.touches.length == 1) {
                var touch = e.touches[0];
                touchStartX = touch.pageX;
            }
        }).on('touchmove', function (event) {
            var e = event.originalEvent;
            if (touchStartX != null) {
                var touchCurrentX = e.changedTouches[0].pageX;
                if ((touchCurrentX - touchStartX) > 60) {
                    touchStartX = null;
                    $carousel.carousel('prev');
                } else if ((touchStartX - touchCurrentX) > 60) {
                    touchStartX = null;
                    $carousel.carousel('next');
                }
            }
        }).on('touchend', function () {
            touchStartX = null;
        });
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Here is the link for working demo - https://jsfiddle.net/L5begcz5/

Comment: This solves my issue quick and easy instead of debugging! Thanks!