# Disable vertical scrolling ONLY when swiping left or right - Carousel Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, css, carousel, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

I found this below code online on Stack Overflow but I am not happy about using this CSS for my Carousel Bootstrap 4.

```
.carousel {
touch-action: none;
}
```

Because users will not know maybe how to scroll, the carousel takes up the whole mobile screen almost.

So is there a way that the vertical scroll ONLY will be disabled IF i SWIPED left or right. And just activate the vertical scrolling again if i just touch and go down.

Is it possible to target code on the way the fingers move? If I move left to right block vertical scrolling and if I move up to down enable vertical scrolling.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        (function ($) {

            var touchStartX = null;

            $('.carousel').each(function () {
                var $carousel = $(this);
                $(this).on('touchstart', function (event) {
                    var e = event.originalEvent;
                    if (e.touches.length == 1) {
                        var touch = e.touches[0];
                        touchStartX = touch.pageX;
                    }
                }).on('touchmove', function (event) {
                    var e = event.originalEvent;
                    if (touchStartX != null) {
                        var touchCurrentX = e.changedTouches[0].pageX;
                        if ((touchCurrentX - touchStartX) > 60) {
                            touchStartX = null;
                            $carousel.carousel('prev');
                        } else if ((touchStartX - touchCurrentX) > 60) {
                            touchStartX = null;
                            $carousel.carousel('next');
                        }
                    }
                }).on('touchend', function () {
                    touchStartX = null;
                });
            });

        })(jQuery);
      });
```

Comment: What have you tried? You [copy pasted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50328428/9942418) the whole code without giving it a try.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy Hello thanks for your comment. Of course i tried the code. That's why i dont like the result. It should scroll if i touch UP and DOWN. And vertical scroll should be disabled if i touch LEFT to RIGHT

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy What ive tried is only the above CSS. Cause i am not good at javascript.